# Cardinality of consecutive power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be an arbitrary set. The power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ has the cardinality $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}$

Now if we consider the power set of the power set of $A$, then the cardinality of that power set becomes $$|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))|=2^{|\mathcal{P}(A)|}\Rightarrow 2^{2^{|A|}}$$
I see that the cardinality of consecutive power sets increases by a power of $2$. I am wondering what is the generalized version of this property.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘generalised version’?

Comment: I suppose you could write $|\mathcal{P}^{\circ n}(A)|=(x\mapsto2^x)^{\circ n}|A|$.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku; Something approximating a formula for the n^th inclusive power set. Or that which @J.G; wrote

Comment: No need to assume $A$ is nonempty.